# FK column to mulitple tables POCO

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, poco

I'm trying to stay in POCO, but I'm at an impasse:

```
Public class Alpha()
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("")]
        public int BetaId { get; set; }

        public virtual BetaA BetaA{ get; set; }
        public virtual BetaB BetaB{ get; set; }
}

Public class BetaA()
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
}

Public class BetaB()
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get Alpha.BetaId to be both ForeignKey to BetaA.ID and BetaB.ID in POCO?

If anyone else stumble around this

**Solution I used**

```
Public class Alpha()
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int BetaId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BetaId")]    
        public virtual BetaA BetaA{ get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BetaId")]
        public virtual BetaB BetaB{ get; set; }
}

Public class BetaA()
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
}

Public class BetaB()
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have BetaA and BetaB share a primary key then reference BetaB via BetaA

You can also decorate the nav properties with the foreign key attribute and specify the int property as the FK for both, though I have not tested this scenario myself (I'm on a mobile device).  Give it a shot and let me know!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 
I decorated nav property.

Comment: My concern with this approach is what happens when you assign BetaA and BetaB with different ID values - one of the two expected values will not save

Comment: Hmm.. I see your point - but due to the ETL process, these values shouldn't be allowed to be inserted.